# Delay view transition in ionic rc 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, transition, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic rc4.

I've got multiple views with background images (inline base 64 encoded in the css). On iOS I got the problem that the background is not rendered until the transition has ended. This feels like a short flash and is pretty unaesthetic.

I guess ionic creates the new dom element for the following view and instantly starts the transition. For performance reasons the iOS Safari stops rendering the dom while transitions are in action. I think this might cause the issue.

Is there a way one can delay the transition after the dom creation? This way I could ensure that safari has enough time to pre-render the view's background.

Thanks in advance!